# How PHP file will know and process a function through this callback parameter?

Tags: php, jsonp

I am finding way to get data JSON from PHP file without knowing the function PHP file is processing.

```
<script>
function clickButton(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "jsonp_demo_db.php?callback=myDisplayFunction";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check more about this code at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp

Answer (score 0):

send the function name with get request and check if is Get value exist 
and use `call_user_func($functionName)` and if there is parameter with function you can use `call_user_func_array($functionName , $pramaters)`

```
`function test()
{
  echo "string";
}

if ($_GET['func']) {
  $func = $_GET['func'];
  call_user_func($func);
}`
```

you can also use function_exists to enshure if the function exist and this function return False or True
this code Example :

```
if(function_exists('my_function'))
{
throw new Exception("'my_function' is already defined!");
}

function my_function()
{
  // Do the work here
}
```